# Local disk recomendations for Hyper-V 2012 nodes?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, cluster, hardware

Are there any local hard drive recommendations for Hyper-V 2012 nodes, running in cluster using SAN for VM's?

Are the local hard drive only used for running the Hypervisor or is it used for paging/swapping for the running VM's.

Should the smallest/cheapest disk be good enough or should we use fast disks running raid for the local store on our nodes?

Comment: Right at the top of our FAQ it says we don't do recommendations, please read it before posting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local disks on clustered Hyper-V servers are only used to host the parent operating system, unless you also store local VMs on them. Thus, their performance and size really don't matter much.

Hyper-V doesn't swap out VM memory, unless you are using dynamic memory *and* there is memory overcommitment on the host system; and, even in this case, it usually relies on the guest O.S. memory manager, in order to have the guest system use its own page file. The swap file on the host system is almost never used.

Comment: Hyper-V 2012 can do no-shared clustered storage. It's really not a good idea for what should be obvious reasons, but it does work. It's perfectly valid to disable swap on the Host OS for the reasons you cite too.